# matplotlib tkinter is very slow and freeze when redrawing 2D plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, tk-toolkit

I am trying to build a simple time series viewer which will have a next button to skip to the next time series and a play button which will iterate throughout the time series dataset. The code is surprisingly super slow (1 frame per second), even if I use `set_ydata`. Is this as good as python get? When I press the play button the program freezes after 5-6 slides.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
import scipy
from scipy import io

class Viewer:
    _rawData = None
    _featureMatrix = None
    _root = None
    _t = None
    _index = 0
    _T = None
    _N = None
    _plot = None
    _nextButton = None
    _figure = None
    _axes = None
    _canvas = None
    _toolbar = None
    def __init__(self, rawData, featureMatrix = []):
        # keep local copy of data
        self._rawData = rawData
        self._featureMatrix = featureMatrix
        self._T = rawData.shape[1]
        self._N = rawData.shape[0]
        self._t = numpy.arange(self._T)
        # GUI SETUP
        self._root = Tk()
        self._nextButton = Button(self._root, text="next", command = self.next)
        self._nextButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self._playButton = Button(self._root, text="play", command = self.play)
        self._playButton.grid(row=1, column=0)
        # init figure
        self._figure = pyplot.figure()
        self._axes = self._figure.add_subplot(111)
        self._canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self._figure, master=self._root)
        self._toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self._canvas, self._root)
        self._canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=1)
        self._toolbar.grid(row=1,column=1)
        # draw first time series
        self.draw_ts()
        self._root.mainloop()
    def next(self):
        self._index = self._index + 1 % self._N
        self.draw_ts()
    def play(self):
        for i in range(self._N): self.next()
    def draw_ts(self):
        pyplot.clf() # clear figure
        #if self._plot is None:
        self._plot, = pyplot.plot(self._t, self._rawData[self._index, :]) # the annoying comma is to output an object and not a list of objects
        #else:
        #    self._plot.set_ydata(self._rawData[self._index, :])
        pyplot.title("time series index # %d / %d" % (self._index, self._N))
        #self._axes.relim()
        #self._axes.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
        self._canvas.draw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = numpy.random.random([1000, 100])
    iv = Viewer(x)
```

Comment: you want to look into `blit`ing

Comment: have you tried setting the data of the axis instead of re-plotting?

Answer (score 0):

oops, I think it was pyplot.clf() which caused the long delay. Now it works faster (still a bit slow ~ 7 Hz). If I turn on play, it again freezes after few slides. I think it because it tries to draw before finishing the previous drawing or something like that.